# PHP help creating seprate page newbie here

Tags: php

Hello I am a total beginner and trying to learn php by watching some youtube videos. So far I have learned how to insert and view data my mysql. But I am a bit stuck on the next part. Basically I created a table that will hold printers information(ip address, model # etc) I have a printers.php page that lists them all in a table that gets pulled in from the database. So far so good.
What I am trying to do now is create a link for each of the printers that get put in the database. So when I click on Model # it will take me to the page for that particular printer.

Here is my modelsample.php template file

```
 <?php
include('includes/PrintFunctions.php');
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $mod ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
<tr>
<td>Brand</td><td><?php echo $bran; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Model:</td><td><?php echo $mod; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Office:</td><td><?php echo $off; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Location:</td><td><?php echo $loc; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>IP Address:</td><td><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>MAC Address:</td><td><?php echo $mac; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ink Type:</td><td><?php echo $Ink; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my prinFunctions.php code

```
   function getPrinters2() {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM printers") or die (mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">No Printers Were Found</td></tr>";
} else {
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$bran=$post['Brand'];
$mod=$post['Model'];
$off=$post['Office'];
$loc=$post['Location'];
$ip=$post['IPAddress'];
$mac=$post['MACAddress'];
$Ink=$post['Ink Order'];
$Stock=$post['Stock'];
$id=$post['id'];
echo "<tr><td>" . $bran . "</td><td>" .  '<a href="/web/printer%202/printer/admin/modsample.php?id='.$post['Model'].'">'.$post['Model'].'</a>' . "</td><td>" . $off . "</td><td>" . $loc . "</td><td>" . $ip . "</td><td>" . $mac. "</td><td>" .  $Ink . "</td><td>" . $Stock . "</td><td><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $id . "\">Delete</a><br /><a href=\"edit.php?id=" . $id . "\">Edit</a></td></tr>";
}
}
}
```

Basically what I am trying to achive is when the printer.php page lists all the printers, when I click on the Model it will take me to a separate page for the particular Model

Thanks for your help

Comment: So next page is not working after clicking or some other problems ?

Comment: I don't recommend getting in the habit of using naked php in your html.  Much better to start out with a templating engine, it'll save you trouble later, and give you much more readable html.  http://smarty.net or https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php are useful choices.

Comment: Yeah, when I click the model it takes me to the modsample.php?id=printermodel
but all I get is  
Notice: Undefined variable: off in C:\wamp\www\web\printer 2\printer\admin\modsample.php on line 24
for all the variables

Answer (score 0):

then you need to add anchor tag in model `<a>` and point `href` attributr to other page where you will be displaying you printer of that partcular model..

try this

```
...
<tr>
 <td>Model:</td><td><a href="PrinterByModel.php?model=<?php echo $mod ?>"><?php echo $mod; ?></a></td>
</tr> 
...
```

PrinterByModel.php

```
$model=$_GET['model']; //here you will get the clicked model name
// db query to get details of printer of the clicked model
//and dislay the values in table like in modelsample.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am not sure what to put in the PrinterByModel.php page
I already have a modelsample.php page, which I was hoping for the template

Comment: you need to make sure what you want in PrinterByModel first.... think about it... i thought you wanted to display the printers details of that particular Model there in  PrinterByModel..

Comment: So I think I can clear this up, say you've a query like: `SELECT * FROM printers` to get all the printers on printers.php. What you're looking for to get data about just one printer is `SELECT * FROM printers WHERE model = $model`. This will give you data about just that printer so you can then display it individually

Comment: thanks... :) :) @Niall... i think he is not sure of what he wants.. :)

Comment: Right, where exactly do I place that SELECT * FROM printers WHERE model = $model? In my samplemodel.php page?

Yeah, I already made the template file where I wanted to pull the info for each particular printer
sorry I am totally new at this

Comment: write that in PrinterByModel.php of my example... and  include this in  your template..